# cron jobs stored in /etc/cron.d work but don't display with crontab -l in RHEL4

Tags: rhel, cron

I thought I understood cron but it appears that I don't.

I am using cron on Red Hat Enterprise Linux v. 4

We organize cron jobs by storing them in /etc/cron.d.  They are all owned by root. (have root in the cron spec in the .cron file)

When stored there, if coded correctly, the jobs run.

However, even though logged in as root

```
crontab -l
```

does not list the jobs in /etc/cron.d, even though they are actually running.

What am I not understanding?  Every web search I've done on this tells me that `crontab -l` is the command to run.  Yet it doesn't list all the jobs it's running.

**UPDATE:** 
Since it wasn't clear, my question is really

> What command lets you see all the cron jobs that are scheduled to run
>   for a given user?

You can find many sources that say `crontab -l` is that command, but that is demonstrably not so.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab)

```
crontab -l
```

lists the crontab for the current user

```
/var/spool/cron/root
```

if you happen to be root.

```
crontab -u other -l
```

for some other user. Edit the crontab with

```
crontab -e
```

Format is

```
#.---------------- minute (0 - 59)
#|      .------------- hour (0 - 23)
#|      |       .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
#|      |       |       .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
#|      |       |       |       .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)  OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
#|      |       |       |       |
#*      *       *       *       *       the command to be executed

0       */2     *       *       *       /every2h.sh
```

In addition to that there is also

```
find  /etc/cron* -type f
```

which is not advisable to use as it's meant for distribution cron jobs. all of those files run as root and are not writable by other users by default.

Comment: Well and good but that doesn't answer the question "what is the command that shows all cron jobs that are scheduled to run"?  crontab -l "lists the crontab for the current user" but that is not a list of all jobs that are scheduled to run for that user.

Comment: Yes, thanks, your update is a more correct version of the answer that I myself gave.

Answer (score 0):

According to `man crontab`, there is `-u` option to append a username.

To show scheduled jobs for a user, usage is:

```
crontab -l -u username
```

And you need to have super user privileges to user it. If you are not the `root` user, then use it as:

```
sudo crontab -l -u username
```

And, according to `man crond` and `/etc/crontab`, there is no command to show the users owning the jobs. The owners of the jobs are saved in the files with this structure:

```
# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name  command to be executed
```

Thus, I think you will have to look for usernames in each file or write a bash script to select and list them.

Also, check this question: [What's the difference between /etc/cron.d and /var/spool/cron?](https://serverfault.com/questions/325340/whats-the-difference-between-etc-cron-d-and-var-spool-cron#325344)

Comment: That doesn't help either.  The basic problem is that there are two systems, the crontab system and the /etc/cron.d system.  There doesn't seem to be anything that shows both a single schedule for both systems.

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

`cat /etc/cron.d/*`  seems to show the same type of listing for those items deployed there as `crontab -l` displays for those items deployed through crontab.